# How to validate the drop down box using press key in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I need to validate the dropdown box using keyboard action. I written the script but it throws error

```
    *** Variables ***

    ${dropdown_button}          css=.list > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > mat-icon:nth-child(1) > svg:nth-child(1)
    ${dropdown_list_1}             css=.list > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1)
    ${dropdown_list_2}             css=.list > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)
    ${dropdown_list_3}             css=.list > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3)

   *** Keywords ***

    Click Element "${dropdown_button}"
    Sleep  3s
    Press Key  ${dropdown_list_1}  \ue015    #Down arrow
    Press Key  ${dropdown_list_2}  \ue015    #Down arrow
    Press Key  ${dropdown_list_3}  \ue013    #up arrow
    Press Key  ${dropdown_list_2}  \ue007    #Pressing enter
```

Comment: what error does it throw?

Comment: Selenium2Library keywords says `key is either a single character, a string, or a numerical ASCII code of the key lead by '\\'.` you are using `'\'`